# No matching constructor for initialization of 'QQmlListProperty<Player>'

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qt6

new bee here on QT.

I am trying to build an online example that used to work on QT5, but the compilation keeps failing on QT6. I keep getting this error and not sure why.

```
    footballteam.cpp:55:12: No matching constructor for initialization of 'QQmlListProperty<Player>'
    qqmllist.h:76:5: candidate constructor not viable: 
    no known conversion from 'int (*)(QQmlListProperty<Player> *)' 
    to 'QQmlListProperty<Player>::CountFunction'
    (aka 'long long (*)(QQmlListProperty<Player> *)') for 4th argument
```

Code:

```
    QQmlListProperty<Player> FootBallTeam::players()
    {
        return QQmlListProperty<Player>(this,this,&FootBallTeam::appendPlayer,
                                        &FootBallTeam::playerCount,
                                        &FootBallTeam::player,
                                        &FootBallTeam::clearPlayers);
    }
```

Classes:

```
class FootBallTeam : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString title READ title WRITE setTitle NOTIFY titleChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString coatch READ coatch WRITE setCoatch NOTIFY coatchChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(Player * captain READ captain WRITE setCaptain NOTIFY captainChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<Player> players READ players  NOTIFY playersChanged)


... bunch of stuff

 private:
    //Callback Methods
    static void appendPlayer(QQmlListProperty<Player>*, Player*);
    static int playerCount(QQmlListProperty<Player>*);
    static Player* player(QQmlListProperty<Player>*, int);
    static void clearPlayers(QQmlListProperty<Player>*);
....


class Player : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QString name READ name WRITE setName NOTIFY nameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool playing READ playing WRITE setPlaying NOTIFY playingChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString position READ position WRITE setPosition NOTIFY positionChanged)
public:
    explicit Player(QObject *parent = nullptr);

    QString name() const;
    bool playing() const;
    QString position() const;
    void setName(QString name);
    void setPlaying(bool playing);
    void setPosition(QString position);

signals:
    void nameChanged(QString name);
    void playingChanged(bool playing);
    void positionChanged(QString position);
   
private :
    QString m_name;
    bool m_playing;
    QString m_position;
};
```

I looked into this thread, but did not help much.

[Pass QQmlListProperty from QML to C++ as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55047211/pass-qqmllistproperty-from-qml-to-c-as-parameter)

Any ideas why it does not compile on QT6?

thank you.

Comment: They changed the return type of `QQmlListProperty::CountFunction` from `int` to `qsizetype` in Qt6, this is why the compiler complaints about the conversion of 4th argument. Compare: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html#CountFunction-alias and https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qqmllistproperty.html#CountFunction-typedef

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by absolute.madnes, the fix was to change int to qsizetype

```
qsizetype FootBallTeam::playerCount(QQmlListProperty<Player> * list)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<FootBallTeam*>(list->data)->playerCountCustom();
}

Player *FootBallTeam::player(QQmlListProperty<Player> * list, qsizetype index)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<FootBallTeam*>(list->data)->playerCustom(index);
}
```